# Grails: LDAP-Authentication with RememberMe-Functionality

Tags: grails, ldap, spring-security

following scenario:

I've an grails application. The Users gets authenticated via LDAP (using spring-security-ldap plugin). This works fine.
But now, I want to use the 'rememberMe'-functionality of the spring-security-framework. 
So I created a persistentLogin-Domain Class.

When I login to my application, a token (and a username, last_used_timestamp, series) is created an saved to the database.

But when I close the browser and open it again, the token is still in the database but I have to logon again.

(Yes, the controller which I want to access supports remembered users...

```
@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'))
```

Does someone has experience with it and could give me some tips?

Comment: Can you help me in ldap authentication? I've installed spring security ldap plugin but ldap authentication doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? Did you read already the docs to the spring ldap plugin?